# wp_insert_post removes information when updating

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm using a front-end form and `wp_insert_post` to update posts from the front-end of a website - in order to do this I am using:

```
'ID' => get_the_ID(),
```

to make sure it is updating the current post (the form appears on the posts page). I am using the below to edit the post content:

```
'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
```

(this takes the result from a submitted form).

However, on save the information is submitted in to the post but all other post data seems to be reset such as the title and post password.

Is there any way to stop this happening? it seems like some very odd default functionality.

Comment: Post all of the relevant code please.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: You probably want `wp_update_post` but I don't have time to replicate the problem and try to test it.

Comment: Doh! You are correct - glad it's such a simple thing. Pop this as the answer and I'll accept :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. `wp_insert_post()` is for creating posts. You need `wp_update_post()` if you want to update existing data.